# Не отправляются данные формы HTML&PHP на почту

Tags: php, wordpress, form, textarea

Столкнулся с проблемой. Форма не отправляет данные. Приходит пустое письмо на почту. Только заголовок и отправитель. Сайт на Wordpress

Вот код:

```html
<div class="form_back">
<p class="text"><h1>Contact to us</h></p>

<?php        
   $to      = "blabla@mail.com";
   $subject = 'New message for you';
   $message = $_POST['mess']; 
   $headers = 'From: info@mail.com';
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>

<form action="" action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?> " method="post">

<ol style="list-style-type: none;">
 
  <div><h5>Your name</h5></div>
  
  <li><input type="text" name="name" required="required"/></li>
  
  <div><h5>Your email</h5></div>
  
  <li><input type="text" name="email" required="required"/></li>
  
  <div><h5>Message</h5></div>
  
  <li><textarea name="mess"></textarea></li>
  
  <li><h4><input type="submit" value="Send message" name="submit"></h4></li>

</ol>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Только что проверил, все работает!

Comment: А что в `$_POST['mess']`, вы проверяли? Может там пусто ...

Answer (score 1):

Если сайт стоит на localhost'е, то сообщение и не может приходить.
Лучше используйте `wp_mail()` вместо просто `mail()`, так как у Вас сайт на вп.

Answer (score 0):

1. Используйте не php `mail`, а `wp_mail` вот ссылка на [документацию](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) или [вот](http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_mail), если на буржуйском не понимаете.
2. Скорее всего ваше письмо приходит в спам во всяком случае что находится в массиве `$_POST`.
3. Если не особо разбираетесь в php `mail` и `smtp`, используйте плагины к примеру *Contact Form 7* для формирования форм отправки и их обработки и *WP Mail SMTP* для настройки SMTP.

Comment: @Alex очепятался да $_POST